# Drawable Reference

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I have few images in my app ( they are all copied into res/drawable and have appropriate R.drawable reference) that I want to assign them to my ImageViews using contents of an string type variable. To illustrated,  I have an image file named "c4.png" in my drawable folder and an string variable (card) that contains "c4". I want to see if there is any way I can use a code like this (ImageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.card)) to assign image c4 to my ImageView1 instead of using ImageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.c4). Basically, I am wondering if it is possible to replace a variable with the specific image name in the R.drawable.resourceName. I know that R.drawable.resourceName is an integer and I am not trying to change its type. I want to replace the resourceName with a variable. I appreciate any help

Comment: May I know what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I know how to group images into array then use that array to set image resource. But I dont understand why you are changing name of the image.

Comment: @mussharapp it's a card game, a card is randomly being picked and displayed. I have a method that generate a random string such as c4 that refers to one of the the card images (let say i have 10 images from c1 to c10) the method will randomly choose one and return it as a string "c4" for example. now I want to use this string "c4" wich is identical to my drawable resource name to update the card image on my UI.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh I am not changing the name of the image. the name is exactly the same. i just want to use a variable that contains the image name instead of the image direct name so the variable could take any other image name that I have in my drawable. I provided more info in reply to the last comment. When i go with ImageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.c4) it updates my UI with c4 image but I cannot do ImageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.card) while card is a variable containing value "c4".

Comment: Ok. I think you have to randomly choose a number instead of string. And using that number you can pick image from image array.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh can you guide me to the solution on grouping images into array and using that to set the image resource. I might be able to find a work around for my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to draw a random number in particular range-

```
int min = 0;
int max = 9;

Random r = new Random();
int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

Then using this number pick image from image array-

```
public Integer[] nImages = {
                R.drawable.c1, R.drawable.c2,
                R.drawable.c3, R.drawable.c4,
                R.drawable.c5, R.drawable.c6,
                R.drawable.c7, R.drawable.c8,
                R.drawable.c9, R.drawable.c10
    };

ImageView1.setBackgroundResource(nImages [i1]);
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Resources res = getResources();

int id = res.getIdentifier(card, "drawable", getPackageName());
img.setImageResource(id);
```

this may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can put the images in the asset folder. Assets are referenced by their filename, as in

```
getAssets().open(<filename>);
```

This returns an InputStream. Afterwhich it is trivial to convert them to a Bitmap resource

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

And then use that bitmap for your ImageView. That should be straightforward with

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to replace the resourceName with a variable.

Instead of declaring the variable card as a string declare it as an Integer. So that you can use it like the following.

```
int card=R.drawable.c4;
ImageView1.setImageResource(card);
```

You probably can not do something like R.drawable.card because the R file is generated according to the resources in the drawable folder. 
hope this helps

Comment: the integer that goes to setImageResource as its argument should refer to the exact value of the resource as it is represented in the R.java. I can change my method to supply an integer for card but it wont be the same value that exist in class R.